# Allow my code to show 0 instead of rounding up using ceil

Tags: php, unix, timestamp, ceil

i am trying to use two unix time stamps to determine the time in days between the two.

I am using this:

```
$days_Since_Updated = ceil(abs(time() - $lastupdated) / 86400);
```

The last updated variable is saved in my database as a unix stamp aswell.

This code works perfectly fine, but only shows 1 as a minimum number.

How can i have it so that the code returns a number that can be 0? Currently it will show 1 if the number is actually less than a day difference between the two.

I know ceil rounds up, not sure whats another better method is? Thanks!

Comment: [ceil()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php) rounds up, [floor()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php) rounds down.... the PHP docs actually tell you this in the "see also" section

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: simple as that! floor() worked fine. Im making a days since last update feature on blog posts.

Comment: @user2921557: Just use DateTime objects and be done with it: https://eval.in/138540

Comment: Didn't know about that feature of php. I'll try implemented that! Thanks!